# Python - How do I highlight a word in a string?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a program to solve word search puzzles, and to show the user where the words are, I want to capitalize all the matching words in a string.

For example, 
`'randomtextfoorandomtext'`

Turns into
`'randomtextFOOrandomtext'`

I was thought about using list comprehension but I am unsure about how use it in this way.

Comment: try using `string.replace('lower_case', 'upper_case')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to achive this is with the [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```
puzzle = 'randomtextfoorandomtext'
word = 'foo'
highlighted = puzzle.replace(word, word.upper())
```